# `expo run:android` Build Compatibility Error, but Build in Android Studio success

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, build, expo

### Description

When running the android project through Android Studio, it built successfully (of course it will error because the react server not running). But, something wierd will happen when we try to run `expo run:android` -which is basically run the same command (plus run the react dev server)- it will error with log looks like below.

### Environment

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 14.0
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
    Memory: 91.08 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.15.0 - ~/Library/Caches/fnm_multishells/74130_1692514877370/bin/node
    npm: 9.5.0 - ~/Library/Caches/fnm_multishells/74130_1692514877370/bin/npm
    pnpm: 8.6.12 - ~/Library/pnpm/pnpm
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.0, iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, tvOS 17.0, visionOS 1.0, watchOS 10.0
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 31, 33
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 30.0.3, 33.0.0, 33.0.2, 34.0.0
      System Images: android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
  Languages:
    Bash: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Java: 1.8.0_362 - /usr/bin/javac
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 116.0.5845.96
    Safari: 17.0
  npmPackages:
    @babel/core: ^7.22.10 => 7.22.10 
    @tsconfig/react-native: ^3.0.2 => 3.0.2 
    @types/react: ^18.2.20 => 18.2.20 
    @types/react-native-shared-group-preferences: ^1.1.1 => 1.1.1 
    @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin: ^6.4.0 => 6.4.0 
    @typescript-eslint/parser: ^6.4.0 => 6.4.0 
    eslint: ^8.47.0 => 8.47.0 
    eslint-config-prettier: ^9.0.0 => 9.0.0 
    eslint-plugin-prettier: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0 
    eslint-plugin-react: ^7.33.2 => 7.33.2 
    eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort: ^10.0.0 => 10.0.0 
    expo: ~49.0.7 => 49.0.7 
    expo-build-properties: ~0.8.3 => 0.8.3 
    expo-splash-screen: ~0.20.5 => 0.20.5 
    expo-status-bar: ~1.6.0 => 1.6.0 
    expo-system-ui: ^2.4.0 => 2.4.0 
    prettier: ^3.0.2 => 3.0.2 
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.72.4 => 0.72.4 
    react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view: ^0.9.5 => 0.9.5 
    react-native-really-awesome-button: ^2.0.4 => 2.0.4 
    react-native-root-toast: ^3.4.1 => 3.4.1 
    react-native-shared-group-preferences: ^1.1.23 => 1.1.23 
    react-native-widget-bridge: ^0.1.3 => 0.1.3 
    typescript: ^5.1.6 => 5.1.6
```

### Error Log

```
   14:35  ﱮ RNWidget    main ✘!?+74 via  v0.7.3 via  v18.15.0 
 ✗  bun run android                              
$ expo run:android
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'React Native Widget'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
brew install openjdk@17

# If Apple Silicon
# sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk\@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

# If Intel
# sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk\@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```